# Want to delete some data from json file using python

Tags: python, json

Hi I wanted to delete some data from my json file using python with tkinter

this is the data in the json file :

```
[
 {
  "username":name,
  "password":userpassword,
  "usertype":usertype
 },

 {
  "username":name1,
  "password":userpassword1,
  "usertype":usertype1
 },

 {
  "username":name2,
  "password":userpassword2,
  "usertype":usertype2 
 }

]
```

and I wanted it to become like this using python coding

```
[
 {
  "username":name,
  "password":userpassword,
  "usertype":usertype
 },

 {
  "username":name2,
  "password":userpassword2,
  "usertype":usertype2
 }

]
```

Comment: Your data is invalid, you have duplicate keys. Please provide the exact and real data. A list of dict perhaps ?

Comment: Those are not valid JSON files. There can only be one "username" key per dict.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to correct your json then you can try something like this:

```
json = [{
    "username": "name",
    "password": "userpassword",
    "usertype": 'usertype'}, {

    "username": "name1",
    "password": "userpassword1",
    "usertype": 'usertype1'}, {

    "username": "name2",
    "password": "userpassword2",
    "usertype": 'usertype2'

}]
for idx, item in enumerate(json):
    if item['username'] == 'name1':
        json.pop(idx)
print(json)
```

Comment: sorry and yes I have corrected my json file and question. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @yanhonwong I hope my answer is working for you

Answer (score 0):

`users.json`

```json
[
    {
        "username": "name,",
        "password": "userpassword,",
        "usertype": "usertype"
    },
    {
        "username": "name1",
        "password": "userpassword,",
        "usertype": "usertype"
    },
    {
        "username": "name2",
        "password": "userpassword,",
        "usertype": "usertype"
    }
]
```

`delete_user.py`

```py
import json


with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.loads(f.read())

users = [user for user in users if not user["username"] == "name1"]
print(users)

# To write the changes back to the file
with open("users.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(users))
```

Output:

```
[{'username': 'name,', 'password': 'userpassword,', 'usertype': 'usertype'}, {'username': 'name2', 'password': 'userpassword,', 'usertype': 'usertype'}]
```